# Why is Haskell lookup function causing Non-Exhaustive pattern error on custom data type?

Tags: haskell, lookup, algebraic-data-types, custom-data-type, non-exhaustive-patterns

Anyone know why this is causing the error `Non-exhaustive patterns in function getCityPopulation`?

```hs
type Name = String
type Coordinates = (Int, Int)
type Pop = Int
type TotalPop = [Pop]
type City = (Name, (Coordinates, TotalPop))

testData :: [City]
testData = [("New York City", ((1,1), [5, 4, 3, 2])),
           ("Washingotn DC", ((3,3), [3, 2, 1, 1])),
           ("Los Angeles", ((2,2), [7, 7, 7, 5]))]

getCityPopulation :: [City] -> Name -> Int -> Maybe (Coordinates, TotalPop)
getCityPopulation [] nameIn yearIn = error "Can't be empty"
getCityPopulation [cs] nameIn yearIn
    | nameIn == "" = error "Input City name"
    | yearIn == 0 || yearIn < 0 = error "invalid year"
    | otherwise = lookup nameIn [cs]
```

As you can see, I've tried to add a case for when any of the parameters may be empty or just invalid for the lookup function. What else could it be?

Also, I know the `yearIn` variable is redundant at the moment, it will be pertinent later, for the intended function use, which will be to get the `yearIn` element of the TotalPop list.

Thanks in advance for any and all help that is given :)

Comment: If you enable warnings (strongly recommended) with `-Wall`, GHC should warn you and point out the missing cases which are not handled by your function. In the warning, something like `_:_:_` should point to a list having at least two elements, which is not handled by your code as explained in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[cs]` there means a list of **one** *city* (list-item) bound to `cs` - I think you want this - so there is no case for lists with more than zero or one elements - the error is telling you that.

```hs
getCityPopulation :: [City] -> Name -> Int -> Maybe (Coordinates, TotalPop)
getCityPopulation [] nameIn yearIn = error "Can't be empty"
getCityPopulation cs nameIn yearIn
    | nameIn == "" = error "Input City name"
    | yearIn == 0 || yearIn < 0 = error "invalid year"
    | otherwise = lookup nameIn cs
```

now the 3rd entry matches *any* list and binds it to `cs` but as the case before already catched empty-lists `cs` will have at least one element.

Btw: I don't think you need this - why throw errors (crash the program) when you are returning a `Maybe` anyway? - also you never use `yearIn` aside from checking it.

I'd recommend just

```hs
tryGetCityPopulations :: [City] -> Name -> Maybe TotalPop
tryGetCityPopulations cs nameIn = snd <$> lookup nameIn cs
```

this way the function does what the name implies and you can go on with the result as you see fit.